# Render HTML with Javascript without specifying it like string (ReactJS alternative)

Tags: jsx, babeljs

Is it possible to use JSX syntax for rendering HTML in Javascript without Babel transforming it to ReactJS component? Or maybe another engine that could do this?

Comment: The deprecated JSX transformer from react-tools? Babel is the most current option.

Comment: 'JSX transformer from react-tools' will translate: *function a() { text = "hello"; return <div> { text } </div>;*  to *function a() { text = "hello"; return "<div>" + text + "</div>";*  ??

Comment: It transforms JSX syntax into pure JS. So `return (JSX here)`

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out

Comment: I don't recommend it because it's been deprecated since React 0.14 I believe, in favor of Babel. Try not to use something deprecated as it has compatibility issues and makes maintainability harder.

Comment: Generally I don't care if it is deprecated, i just want the feature of 'not writing strings' for rendering html in js, as long as it works like this, is good enough, because i am not using reactjs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123654/discussion-between-jovan-meshkov-and-andrew-l).